# Making AuthorizeAttribute deny users by default if Roles is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I'm rather surprised at the default behaviour of `AuthorizeAttribute`; if you don't supply it any `Roles` property, it just appears to allow *any* authorized user to access the controller/action.  I want whitelist behaviour instead; if `Roles` is null or empty, *deny* all users access.  How can I make this behaviour occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I came up with eventually, as a filter I add to the global filter collection for an MVC application:

```
/// <summary>
/// This filter should be applied to an MVC application as a global filter in RegisterGlobalFilters, not applied to individual actions/controllers.
/// It will cause access to every action to be DENIED by default.
/// If an AllowAnonymousAttribute is applied, all authorization checking is skipped (this takes precedence over AuthorizeSafeAttribute).
/// If an AuthorizeSafeAttribute is applied, only the roles specified in AuthorizeSafeAttribute's Roles property will be allowed access.
/// </summary>
public sealed class AuthorizeSafeFilter : AuthorizeAttribute {
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Roles) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Users)) {
            throw new Exception("This class is intended to be applied to an MVC application as a global filter in RegisterGlobalFilters, not applied to individual actions/controllers.  Use the AuthorizeSafeAttribute with individual actions/controllers.");
        }

        // Disable caching for this request
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        // If AllowAnonymousAttribute applied, skip authorization
        if (
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) ||
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)
        ) {
            return;
        }

        // Backup original roles
        string rolesBackup = this.Roles;

        // Look for AuthorizeSafeAttribute roles
        bool foundRoles = false;
        string foundRolesString = null;
        object[] actionCustomAttributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(false);
        object[] controllerCustomAttributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        if (actionCustomAttributes.Any(attr => attr is AuthorizeSafeAttribute)) {
            AuthorizeSafeAttribute foundAttr = (AuthorizeSafeAttribute)(actionCustomAttributes.First(attr => attr is AuthorizeSafeAttribute));
            foundRoles = true;
            foundRolesString = foundAttr.Roles;
        }
        else if (controllerCustomAttributes.Any(attr => attr is AuthorizeSafeAttribute)) {
            AuthorizeSafeAttribute foundAttr = (AuthorizeSafeAttribute)(controllerCustomAttributes.First(attr => attr is AuthorizeSafeAttribute));
            foundRoles = true;
            foundRolesString = foundAttr.Roles;
        }

        if (foundRoles && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foundRolesString)) {
            // Found valid roles string; use it as our own Roles property and auth normally
            this.Roles = foundRolesString;
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else {
            // Didn't find valid roles string; DENY all access by default
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }

        // Restore original roles
        this.Roles = rolesBackup;
    }
}
```

I also define this attribute:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an attribute that is used to restrict access by callers to an action method, in conjunction
/// with a global AuthorizeSafeFilter, DENYING all access by default.
/// </summary>
public class AuthorizeSafeAttribute : Attribute {
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I apply `AllowAnonymousAttribute` to my login actions/controllers and `AuthorizeSafeAttribute` to other ones, but if I forget to apply these, access is *denied* by default.  I wish ASP.NET MVC were as secure as this by default.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
public class AuthorizeExAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Roles))
            return false;
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Now use `[AuthorizeEx]` on your controllers/actions

Comment: I've also added `filters.Add(new AuthorizeExAttribute());` to my `RegisterGlobalFilters` because I want everything to be off-limits by default.  Unfortunately, for some reason, `this.Roles` always seems to be empty now even when I apply `[AuthorizeEx(Roles="Admin")]` for example.  Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Ah, I think the problem is that this approach ignores the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute which I apply to my login controller, so because I don't define roles for that, it always fails to authorize access to the login page.  So, I need a way to check for the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute from the `AuthorizeCore` method.

Comment: I think you want to need to come at this from another angle.  The simplest approach is to have an `Authenticated_Role` which every logged-in user has; then use the standard `AuthorizeAttribute` with that role as the default.  I've done this on my own site and it works absolutely fine.

Comment: What's really annoying is that `OnAuthorization`, where you have access to the `AuthorizationContext`, doesn't let you just return false to deny authorization.  And `AuthorizeCore` doesn't let you get access to the `AuthorizationContext`!