# Owin : How to bar access to not-logged-in users?

Tags: owin

I have an Owin pipeline with a filtering middleware that is meant to reject requests that haven't been authorised by an upstream middleware (cookie auth or stateless auth). The test is as follows...

```
if ((!environment.ContainsKey("server.User") || environment["server.User"] == null) && !RequestIsWhitelisted(environment))
    return AuthChallengeResponse(environment);
```

Even if I remove all the upstream middleware, environment["server.User"] is still populated, with a {System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal} object. I'm guessing this is because I'm placing the request as a logged-in user of the local machine?

What is putting WindowsPrincipal in environment["server.User"]? Can it be stopped? Is my test for "not logged in" the right one?

Comment: Is this a use-case were you can't use the AuthorizeAttribute in your controller methods?

Comment: I can, but is that not a little risky? Forget to add the AuthorizeAttribute and you're wide open?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822113/making-authorizeattribute-deny-users-by-default-if-roles-is-empty